# how to pass a fd to another process?

Tags: linux, sockets, unix

there is a ***fd*** in the ***process A***. ***process A*** fork and call ***exec*** *.

domain socket, fifo, pipe.

is there a simple way to let me get and use this ***fd*** in the new ***process B***?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer.

Comment: Process B has source code that you can modify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open file descriptors are inherited when using fork. There is nothing you should.

From [fork manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html):

```
          The child inherits copies of the parent's set of open file
          descriptors.  Each file descriptor in the child refers to the same
          open file description (see open(2)) as the corresponding file
          descriptor in the parent.  This means that the two file
          descriptors share open file status flags, file offset, and signal-
          driven I/O attributes (see the description of F_SETOWN and
          F_SETSIG in fcntl(2)).
```

As for exec that still holds true (if you didn't mark the fd as close-on-exec). From [execve man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) (all exec* calls are just a wrapper around this system call):

```
By default, file descriptors remain open across an execve(). File descriptors that are marked close-on-exec are closed; see the description of FD_CLOEXEC in fcntl(2).
```

Comment: Good answer with proper quoting, +1

Comment: I know it will be inherited. but, how does child know what variable should this fd be after exec*.

Comment: I mean, for example, fd is 3 in process A. after fork and exec*, how can I  pass this 3 to child.

Comment: @umbreLLaJYL: Your last comments should be incorporated into the question post. Currently, one may only guess that your problem is in passing a value, not about using it.

Comment: You don't really concern yourself with this. If fd was 3 before fork, it will stay 3 after the fork, ie. the variable value will stay the same and opened file descriptor number will stay the same. You don't pass anything to the child, if a variable has been initialized before the fork, child will have the same variable value as the parent has. (The addresses of these variables change, cause they are/may be different virtual address spacees, anyway values of variables are copied from the parent into the childs address space, but this is another topic).